# How to drop all databases starting with prefix in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

In Postgresql I have several databases starting with **hdb** prefix.

What I am looking for is to to forcefully drop all such dbs, terminating existing connections if any.

I tried below way:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _db text;
BEGIN
FOR _db  IN
    SELECT datname FROM pg_stat_activity where datname ilike 'hdb%'
LOOP
    EXECUTE 'REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE ' || _db||' FROM public;';
    EXECUTE 'DROP DATABASE ' || _db;

END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

But that says,

> ERROR:  DROP DATABASE cannot be executed from a function or
>   multi-command string

Comment: Since you can't do it with a database function, write client code.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I drop test databases with a client script (Linux):

```
#!/bin/bash

PREFIX='hdb'
export PGPASSWORD=postgres
export PGUSER=postgres
export PGHOST=localhost
export PGPORT=5432

TEST_DB_LIST=$(psql -l | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep '^[a-z]' | grep -v template | grep -v postgres)
for TEST_DB in $TEST_DB_LIST ; do
    if [ $(echo $TEST_DB | sed "s%^$PREFIX%%") != $TEST_DB ]
    then
        echo "Dropping $TEST_DB"
        dropdb --if-exists $TEST_DB
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to make it OS independent.

Comment: @Pratik With which client (scripting) language?

Comment: As mentioned, using PostgreSQL script.

Comment: And nothing has changed: It is not possible in a database function.

Comment: For more information, check out its reference https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-drop-all-databases-starting-with-prefix-in-postgresql